# Minimal polynomial of a matrix satisfying $A^t=A^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, minimal-polynomials

> Let $A\in M_n(\mathbb R)$ be a non-zero non-identity matrix such that $A^t=A^2$. Then is it possible to find the minimal polynomial of $A$?

My  try is: the given condition implies that $A^4=A$, hence the minimal polynomial $p(t)$ of $A$ divides $t^4-t=t(t-1)(t^2+t+1)$. So $p(t)$ can be some factor of $t(t-1)(t^2+t+1)$.

Also if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ and $x$ is the corresponding eigenvector (considered as a column vector), then $Ax=\lambda x \implies \lambda x^t=x^t A^t\implies \lambda x^t=x^tA^2\implies \lambda(x^t x)=x^t(A^2x)\implies \lambda(x^t x)=\lambda^2(x^tx)\implies (\lambda^2-\lambda)(x^tx)=0\implies\lambda^2-\lambda=0,\text{ as } x^tx \text{ is non-zero}.$

Hence $0$ and $1$ are the only eigenvalues of $A$. So the minimal polynomial is of the form $p(t)=t(t-1).$ Is this correct or did I misunderstood something?

P.S. $A^t$ denotes the transpose of the matrix $A$.

Comment: Looks correct to me

Comment: @fvel: I believe $t$ indicates the transpose...

Comment: @fvel $t$ denotes transposition and not a power

Comment: That's why some denotes the transpose with a math roman *prescript*: $^{\mathrm t\mskip-2mu}A$.

Comment: Where $A^t$ denotes the transpose of the matrix $A$.

Comment: This isn't right. There are $2 \times 2$ matrices $A$ of order $3$ with $A^{t} = A^{2}$, for example $\left( \begin{array}{clcr} \cos \frac{2 \pi}{3} & \sin \frac{2 \pi}{3}\\ -\sin\frac{2 \pi}{3}  & \cos \frac{2 \pi}{3}  \end{array} \right) $. You have overlooked the fact that a real matrix can have a pair of complex conjugate eigenvalues. Note that this example has characteristic polynomial $x^{2}+x + 1.$ There are examples where the min poly really is $x^{4} - x.$

Comment: I dont understand how "the given condition implies that $A^4=A$ ?

Comment: @SrinivasK : Since $A^{2} = A^{t}$, taking transposes gives $(A^{t})^{2} = A$, so then $A^{4} = A.$

Comment: The minimal polynomial should be of the form $t^m (1-t)^n$ where $m+n<= 4$ ?

Comment: @SrinivasK : Well, since $A^{4} = A,$ the minimal polynomial of $A$ must divide $t^{4}-t = t(t-1)(t^{2}+t+1).$

Comment: If you have complex numbers then it is possible that $x^tx=0$ for nonzero vectors $x$.  The eigenvectors of rotation matrices are $[1,i]^t$ and $[1,-i]^t$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since
$$
A^4=\left(A^2\right)^2=\left(A^T\right)^2=\left(A^2\right)^T=\left(A^T\right)^T=A
$$
the minimal polynomial must divide $x^4-x=x(x-1)(x^2+x+1)$.

For example,
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
-\frac12&\frac{\sqrt3}2\\
-\frac{\sqrt3}2&-\frac12
\end{bmatrix}
$$
has minimal polynomial $x^2+x+1$ and $A^2=A^T$.
$$
B=\begin{bmatrix}
-\frac12&\frac{\sqrt3}2&0\\
-\frac{\sqrt3}2&-\frac12&0\\
0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
has minimal polynomial $x^3-1$ and $B^2=B^T$.
$$
C=\begin{bmatrix}
-\frac12&\frac{\sqrt3}2&0\\
-\frac{\sqrt3}2&-\frac12&0\\
0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
has minimal polynomial $x^3+x^2+x$ and $C^2=C^T$.
$$
D=\begin{bmatrix}
-\frac12&\frac{\sqrt3}2&0&0\\
-\frac{\sqrt3}2&-\frac12&0&0\\
0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
has minimal polynomial $x^4-x$ and $D^2=D^T$.

Comment: So if I assume that $A$ is a non-zero non-identity matrix whose characteristic polynomial splits over $\mathbb{R}$, then is it true that $p(t)=t(t-1)$? I am curious to know

Comment: @user149418: the [minimal polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_polynomial_%28linear_algebra%29), $P$, of a matrix, $M$, is the monic polynomial of minimal degree so that $P(M)=0$.