# Number of $n \times n$ $\{0,1\}$-matrices $A$ such that $A^2$ is the transpose of $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, combinatorics

While browsing the OEIS, I saw the above nice question.
The few terms provided suggest that they were found by brute force.

We conjecture that the number of $\{0, 1\}$-matrices, which also satisfy the given condition, can be determined from the recurrence

$$ 2\, a(n - 1)  +  (n^2 - 3 n + 2) \, a(n - 3)  \quad (n \ge 3), $$

starting $ a(0) = 1,\, a(1) = 2,\, a(2) = 4. $ Or, equivalently,  that

$$ a(n) = \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n / 3 \rfloor} \frac{ 2^{n - 3 k}  \,  n!  }{3^k \,  (n - 3 k)! \, k!} \quad (n \ge 0) . $$

Can anyone prove this? The sequence is OEIS [A336614](https://oeis.org/A336614).

Comment: @Bungo, yes, the question is about binary matrices, where the entries are all $0$ or $1$.

Comment: See an important property [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1136363) (not specific to (0,1) matrices...)

Comment: As a lower bound we can at least make block diagonal matrices built out of every combination of 0s, 1s, and either of the two 3x3 permutation matrices down the diagonal since they satisfy $A^2=A^T$. Not sure if these are the only kinds that can work or not.

Comment: the easy case is when $A$ is invertible: $(A^4)= A^T A^T = (A^2)^T = (A^T)^T =A\implies A^3=I\implies A^{-1} =A^2=A^T$ so $A$ is orthogonal and has only 0s and 1s so it is a permutation matrix with order 3 (which implies all cycles have length 1 or 3).  It isn't immediately clear to me how to deal with singular $A$ though.

Comment: The (edited) question states that $\{0,1\}$-matrices and permutation matrices are the same; this isn't correct.  Permutation matrices are just those $\{0,1\}$-matrices with a single $1$ in each row and column.  (Many of the $\{0,1\}$-matrices satisfying $A^2=A^T$ are, in fact, permutation matrices, but not all of them are.)

Comment: Thanks. Corrected.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It helps to think of an $n\times n$ $0/1$ matrix $A$ as a directed graph on $n$ nodes, where self-edges are allowed; there is an edge from $i$ to $j$ iff $A_{ji}=1$.  The transpose $A^T$ is the same graph, but with all arrows reversed.  Note that $(A^T A)_{ii}=\sum_j A^T_{ij} A_{ji}=\sum_{j}A_{ji}^2=\sum_{j}A_{ji}$ is the number of outgoing edges from node $i$, and $(AA^T)_{ii}$ is the number of incoming edges to node $i$.

We have
$$
A^T A=(A^2)A=A^3=A(A^2)=AA^T,
$$
so each node has the same number of outgoing and incoming edges.  Moreover,
$$
(A^T A)^2=A^6=(A^T)^3=A^T A;
$$
so $((A^T A)^2)_{ii}$, which is at least the square of the number of outgoing edges from node $i$, is also *equal* to the number of outgoing edges from node $i$.  We conclude that the outdegree (and indegree) of each node is $0$ or $1$.  So each node either (a) has no edges attached, or (b) is part of a directed cycle of length $\ell\ge 1$.  Finally, since
$$
A^4=(A^T)^2=A,
$$
the cycle lengths must satisfy $4\equiv 1$ (mod $\ell$); and so $\ell=1$ or $\ell=3$.  Put together, this fully characterizes the allowed graphs: each consists entirely of nodes with no edges, $1$-cycles (i.e., disconnected nodes with self-edges), and directed $3$-cycles.

Enumerating the allowed graphs on $n$ nodes is straightforward at this point.  If there are $k$ triangles, with $3k\le n$, then there are $n-3k$ remaining nodes, which can be taken to be isolated or $1$-cycles in $2^{n-3k}$ ways.  We can choose the triangle membership in
$$
\frac{1}{k!}{{n}\choose{3}}{{n-3}\choose{3}}\cdots{{n-3k+3}\choose{3}}=\frac{1}{k!}\times\frac{n!}{3!(n-3)!}\times\frac{(n-3)!}{3!(n-6)!}\times \cdots =\frac{n!}{k!(3!)^k(n-3k)!}
$$
ways (where the denominator of $k!$ is because the order of the triangles doesn't matter) and each triangle can be directed in $2$ ways, so putting it together gives
$$
T_n=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/3 \rfloor}2^{n-3k}2^{k}\frac{n!}{6^k k!(n-3k)!}=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/3 \rfloor}\frac{2^{n-3k} n!}{3^k k!(n-3k)!},
$$
as conjectured.

Comment: Note that the recurrence relation also follows easily from this graph characterization.  If a particular node (of $n$) is either isolated or a $1$-cycle, the remaining $n-1$ nodes can form any allowed graph; if it's part of a $3$-cycle, then the other two nodes in the cycle can be chosen in $(n-1)(n-2)$ ways, and the remaining $n-3$ nodes can form any allowed graph.  So $T_n = 2T_{n-1} + (n-1)(n-2)T_{n-3}$.  The cases $n\le 2$ can't have triangles, so $T_0=1$, $T_1=2$, and $T_2=4$.

Comment: [+1] Remarkable answer.

Comment: Wonderful answer. I am the author of the sequence OEIS: A336614. The conjecture did not come from brute force. The code might imply that brute force was used but that is not the case, some intuition was used. A big shout out to Peter Luschny for reaching out to you guys, and closing this out. Check: OEIS: A336174